# Getting a strange % when printing using a formatted string

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a formatted string to print an message to sys.stderr but I am getting a mysterious % at the end.

If I write:

```
 sys.stderr.write("One argument (file name) expected, got %d" % (len(sys.argv) -1))
```

I get an output of:

`One argument (file name) expected, got 0%`

If I replace it with a print function, it behaves as expected.  Additionally, the % has a white background so it's probably an unrecognised char by my shell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `%` is probably the `zsh` shell marking output that is missing a newline.

`print` adds a newline, add one manually when using `sys.stderr.write()`:

```
sys.stderr.write("One argument (file name) expected, got %d\n" % (len(sys.argv) -1))
```

Comment: Could also be an artifact of `zsh`, which well append a `%` if the last line of output doesn't end in a newline.

Comment: +1 possible, but what kind of system could OP running that has a `%` prompt *and* python? @FatalError explanation seems more plausible

Comment: It was zsh in this case but yes, you are correct.  I've never seen that before (normally my prompt just land on the same line).  Good catch!

Comment: @FatalError: Ah, forgot about that feature. This is a perfect fit.

Comment: @t0mmyt You might want to look at the `PROMPT_SP` option and the related `PROMPT_EOL_MARK` variable in `zsh`.

Comment: Now that the problem is solved, you might consider upgrading to Python's (actually not so, any more) new [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting) feature.